# Store wait_stats automatically and query it whenever required

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, waits

I'm learning `wait_stats` and came up with thought. Is it possible to store wait stats in a table or create a stored procedure or query which will return `wait_stats %` when we execute query or stored procedure? if yes I would like to have query and stored procedure.

Comment: [Configure the Management Data Warehouse (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933864.aspx)

Comment: This may help - [Capturing Wait Stats For A Single Operation](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-stats-for-a-single-operation/)

Answer (score 1):

You could get a monitoring tool like [Idera SQL Diagnostic Manager](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqldiagnosticmanager) or [Dell Spotlight](https://www.quest.com/products/spotlight-on-sql-server-enterprise/) to do all of that for you. If you want to go the manual route and get the wait stats yourself you can check out [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/) from Brent Ozar. You can use that to store wait stats in a table. If you click through the link they give you directions on how to set it up to log to a table.